# When using KVO is it necessary to remove self as an observer of self in -dealloc?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

in my NSObject subclass's -init method the instance adds itself as an observer of some of its own keyPaths in order to trigger an action that should occur any time one of the properties in question is changed. eg.

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"aProperty" options:0 context:nil];
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"anotherProperty" options:0 context:nil];
...
```

My question is, in the class's -dealloc method do I necessarily need to remove the instance as an observer of itself? eg.

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"aProperty"];
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"anotherProperty"];
...
```

The way I figure it, when an object tries to send a message to an object that no long exists then an exception gets thrown, clearly a problem. But in this case, an object that doesn't exist anymore couldn't possibly send messages to itself, so this shouldn't be a problem.

I haven't had any issues with this yet, but it does still kind of bother me since I've never seen it explicitly stated that you can do this.

I'm just trying to avoid having to write a whole bunch of

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath ...]
```

in my -dealloc method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably could get away without removing `self` as an observer, but you shouldn’t. Where you do `addObserver:...` you also have to do `removeObserver:...` later.

But this discussion is irrelevant anyways, because there is no need to observe `self`, just trigger your action in the setter of your property. This leads to clearer, more readable code that actually performs better.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My class has a bazillion properties that all need to trigger an event whenever any one of them changes, so I thought that using KVO and the @synthesized setters would be more convenient than writing a bazillion setters.

Comment: On a quick note, there are legitimate reasons to observe self, e.g. observing a read-only property of the super class (for example when subclassing NSNotification). Also there might be KVO updates which are not triggered by the setter (but by will/didChangeValueForKey: outside of the setter)

Comment: Another reason is `@dynamic` properties in CALayers and Core Data, where writing your own setter would break the automatic setter functionality.